# My computer hangs when memory hits

Tags: 20.04

Can anyone help me with this problem I have when i reach the memory limit?

The computer **crashes completely** and I can no longer use it, just turning off "**forced**" by holding the power button.

[image]

I have noticed that when swap memory is reached the crash occurs.

Description of my computer:

[image]

Comment: search OOM killer on linux and activate it. I think by default it is disabled

Comment: You should find out what consumes so much memory it fills your RAM and swap. When that happens, it is normal the machine becomes unresponsive.

Comment: [This is my favorite OOM Killer page on the 'net](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/it-infrastructure/dev-oom-killer.html). It's old and Oracle, but it's still valid and well worth a read.

Comment: I will look a little more about what you said, tks.